# Bootstrap: Placeing items side by side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a form in bootstrap and AngularJS, and am trying to make a button appear by the side of a text input.  The idea is that this will add to an array (length unknown) I have the backend working but using the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="item_list">Items</label>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{ingr}}</li>
    </ul>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_list" placeholder="Add item"> <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</div>
```

I can't seem to find a class built into bootstrap that will make these sit side-by-side.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2uYH/).

Need to wrap it in an inline form tag:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form"></form>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't very clear. This is a small part of a larger form that I don't want online. It's just this one part.

Comment: @Jacobm001 No problem! The above should still work - modified a bit. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n2uYH/1/) where I made some modifications, tossed a bunch of elements in, but still wrapped the button you wanted in a div with an inline class.